# When should I use databases?

Tags: android, database

I'm building a Trivial-like application. It's just a collection of questions and pictures.

I was designing it so it would keep all its questions, answers and images on a database.

Is this advisable?

When should I use databases and when just resource folders?

How would you implement this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean SQLite database or an external server with database? Or, if you don't know - how many questions/images would you like to have there? More or less - 50/500/50000?

Comment: I meant SQLite. And I was thinking initially around 500 questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resource folder is also a database. To narrow a question litle bit, point is wherther to keep data in structured or unstructured data store. From experience, structured datastore provides some benefits of indexing, searching data analysis and so on. For now you think you just collect data, but later on you find yourself that you want to add some attributes to it, enhance data model etc. From the programing point of view I do not see many differences between datastore as a folder and between datastore as a database. But there is a huge difference in usability and postprocessing. At the end of the day it is just API calls. So my recomendation is to use database, I think Android API comes with sqlite, store question in database and files may be in database or resource folders with pointers in database.

Comment: Thanks @Robert,I had this exact doubt, whether db gave some kind of "compression". But I guess it doesn,t. I was a bit scared of having to store images in BLOBS, so I'll go for text references on the db with the name of the file on resource. You agree?

Comment: Depends on. No need to be scared of using BLOBS and you can make compress api around it but saving them as reference can help to use images more directly in some UCs. For example web aplication can directly load picures from that directory. So yes In first iteration I would go for directory aproach. Swithing to database if not suitable is quite easy. Poit is to start design with structured database data.

Comment: Resource folder is not a database. These are raw xml files and are significantly slower than SQLite.

Comment: I apologize. By resource folder I mean folder with resources. Like typpical HTML resource directory with pics, css and so on. By database I mean any mean by which data is stored and serves as base of data :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you have 500 questions and for every question you plan to have an image, I would consider using an external server to provide you with data. This way you'll have a lightweight app and will only download the questions you need. You can store the downloaded ones in the local database. Additionally, you can keep your app up to date easily this way.

That being said, if you'd like to choose between resources and SQLite, go with SQLite. It's MUCH faster. You shouldn't put images in the database though (I don't think it's even possible in SQLite), but keep references to them there (filename) and keep the actual images on the SD card.

Comment: Complete answer, thx @Michal-k! I thought of that too, but then the app would need connection to the internet. I might go for this on the future. What about keeping images in sqlite as blobs?

Comment: Blobs (especially in something as lightweight as SQLite) can be used to store images, but it'll make your whole database slower. As far as I know it's considered a bad practice unless these are some very small blobs, an icon or something like this.

Just a note on downloading. Did you consider splitting your questions into chapters or something like this? You could allow user to download whole chapter. But it depends on what kind of app you're trying to build (I don't know "Trivial").

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion if the app should be scalable (new questions/new functions/... added later) a database is a the best solution...

If it is just a small/fast app you would only update once then you could keep it simple and use a simple text file or something else...

**EDIT: since I read you want to have about 500 questions, you should really go for a database, you can later always add properties and stuff, sorting things (like difficulty) and stuff is easy with a database... Go for a database I would say!**

Comment: A database will allows you to do complexe actions between data easily, which won't be the case here. But yeah for maintainability and ease-of-use, a database should be better.

Comment: I might want to add fields like "level of difficulty" based on answers on the future.

Comment: @Ferdau if using a text file how would I link questions to images?

Comment: @eskalera: post edited... Well you could just put the imagename as a property like you would do in a database?

Comment: @Ferdau I guess you mean the name of the file I would have to call from my resources afterwards. Ok, got it. Thanks! Still, by your EDIT i guess you mean 500 is quite a lot. I will go for db then